# Why won't my code run when in external.js file but does if in HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to get a `Javascript/jQuery` code snippet to run from an external `.js` file.

It ran fine when within script tags at the bottom of my asp.net html page but now it's in an external `JS` file it doesn't run. I have successfully inserted (dynamically) a link to the external file (Viewable in page source) and been able to fire a popup alert from inside it, so I know the external file is being accessed correctly. I've also got my reference to `JQuery` before the external file, but the following script will not fire / run? any ideas would be great, thanks.

```
$("#<%=sDatepicker.ClientID%>").focus(function () {
  //$(this).blur();
  alert("Handler for .Datepicker called.");
});
```

As  you can see I'm trying to access a `Textbox` with `ID=sDatepicker`, but asp.net adds a `ClientID` before it so I need to get that to find the actual `TextBox`.

I have considered the page may not have loaded and the `TextBox` control may not exist as the external `JS` file is in the `Head` of my document, but I have also tried adding

```
$('document').ready(function () { });
```

around the script in the  JS file, but this doesn't seem to help.

Like I said, it worked fine when in the `HTML` page, but I need to only reference the external file under certain circumstances, so need to add it from my C# code behind dynamically when required.

cheers.

#### update from feedback below in regards possible solution 1.

I now have in my external `JS` file the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () { keypadSuppress(); });
```

and in my `.aspx` `HTML` file I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function keypadSuppress() {
            $("#<%=sDatepicker.ClientID%>").focus(function () {
                $(this).blur();
                alert("Handler for sDatepicker called.");
            });

            $("#<%=eDatepicker.ClientID%>").focus(function () {
                $(this).blur();
                alert("Handler for eDatepicker called.");
            });
    }
</script>
```

#### Update 2

Tried the above code in the Update above and its working fine today (the gremlins must be asleep still). The only change I made was to add an alert to the `Document.ready` function to flag up when it was accessed, but this was not the issue. The above code works fine as is.

Only other thing I needed to do was add a `<div>` around it which I made visible='true' or visible='false' depending on whether I tested for a mobile or not, in my C# code behind using

```
bool IsMobile = Page.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice;
```

Thanks, we got there eventually :)

Comment: It doesn't work because *.js files are not parsed by the ASP.Net runtime, so your `<%= %>` construct will be taken literally.

Answer (score 3):

When the javascript was inline in the HTML, the <%=%> tags were correctly parsed by ASP.NET. When you extract this javascript verbatim into an external file, the ASP.NET parser will not handle this file, so the id tag will not be translated to the correct id as Rory McCrossan already stated.

Now, some possible solutions:

- You can define a function in the external javascript file that you call in some inline javascript on your web page. This inline javascript can use the <%=%> tags and they will be correctly be replaced by the id of your datepicker element.
- You can opt for something else than a server-generated ID to correctly identify  your datepicker. Consider adding a custom css class, or choose the ID yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks to @Rory McCrossan and prgmtc for the clear answers. Just what I needed to know. I'm trying a different way now. I can use the JavaScript code inline but in some circumstances, when the control does not appear on the page, I want to use something like 'if ((("#<%=sDatepicker.ClientID%>") !== undefined) && (("#<%=sDatepicker.ClientID%>") !== null)) {}' but asap.net seems to ignore this and throws a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Comment: The statement <*=sDatePicker.ClientID%> gets evaluated on the server side. If the sDatePicker object does not get instantiated server-side you will receive nullpointer exceptions when trying to access the ClientID property. Your if-check happens in javascript, which will execute in the browser, but the server-side rendering crashes on the nullpointer exception, so the if-check will never get evaluated in the browser. If you really want to go for this approach, you can check whether (sDatePicker != null) server-side and conditionally render some javascript, but this isn't the cleanest solution.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i'd like to do but i'm 10 hours plus now trying to get this to work. All because i'm trying to suppress the keypad popping up on mobile phones.

Comment: Could you post the entire content of the asp page? Moving the javascript-code from inline to an external file should not result in nullpointer exceptions in your asp code.

Comment: It's almost 800 lines long so possibly not a good idea. I'm not getting the nullpointer exception anymore, it just doesn't run the external js code now.  Which It has before. It is like it reads the code in but ignores it. I have put the relevant code in the update in my original posting above if you haven't seen that. I will also see if I can remove as much none related code and post it here. Most Appreciated.